# Batch concatenate ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using colab to automate the concatenation of large numbers of video. i download the video directly from youtube into a batch footage folder in google drive. I am trying to build a script that will automatically resize and concatenate all videos in this folder. Any suggestions?

here is my c

```
!ffmpeg -i tearcash1.mov -i whiteflower1.mp4 -i peta.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:-1:-1,setsar=1[v0]; \
[1:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:-1:-1,setsar=1[v1]; \
[2:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:-1:-1,setsar=1[v2]; \
[v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] testconcat.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

tested on local, not colab, so can be errors:

```
import os
path="/mnt/public/upload/videos/"
WID=720
HEI=480
INP=""
FCT=0
SCA=""
FIL=""

for filename in os.listdir(path):
  if (filename.endswith(".mp4")):
    INP+=f' -i "{path}{filename}"'
    PAD=f"[{FCT}v]"
    SCA+=f"[{FCT}:v]scale={WID}:{HEI}:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad={WID}:{HEI}:-1:-1,setsar=1{PAD};"
    FIL+=f"{PAD}[{FCT}:a]"
    FCT+=1
  else:
    continue

os.system(f'ffmpeg {INP} -filter_complex "{SCA}{FIL}concat=n={FCT}:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 18 -c:a aac -q:a 4 /tmp/output.mkv -y -hide_banner')
```